# How to write awk function

Tags: awk

I have a quick file `file.awk` with

```
function attr(attrname,str,  a) {
    if (!str) str=$0
    match(str,"@" attrname "=([^,/]*)",a)
    return a[1]
}
```

I am getting an error

```
awk: file.awk: line 139: syntax error at or near ,
```

where line 139 is the line with `match()`

Any idea whats wrong with the syntax?

Comment: You need a `;` between each statement. Add this at the end of the lines beginning with `if` and `match`.

Comment: I don't get any errors when I use this function then again a) I can't tell how you're calling this function (or what `$0` consists of) and b) I can't tell if the error really is coming from the `match()` line of code; please update the question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can use to reproduce the error ... something with a line of input data and an `attr()` call that generates the error would be good; fwiw, on my system `awk --version` ==> `GNU Awk 5.1.1`

Comment: Also check your `awk` version: `match(string, regexp [, array])` vs. `match(s, r)`

Comment: @Barmar no, you don't.

Comment: @Barmar the `;` would be needed if the function definition is flattened into a one-liner; as is (ie, statements on separate lines) `awk` uses EOL as a statement delimiter

Comment: You got answers to the question you asked but if you'd like help doing whatever you're trying to do using portable syntax then ask a new question with a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output about that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the non-POSIX 3rd arg to `match()` but not using GNU awk which supports it. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions.

Answer (score 0):

As always, Ed Morton has it correct.  The only reason I'm posting is that I can share with MacOS users that the awk man page includes the answer.

`man awk` yields:

```
  match(s, r)
          the position in s where the regular expression r occurs, or 0 if it does not.  The variables RSTART and RLENGTH are set to the  position  and
          length of the matched string.
```

So it is very clear that your call has an extra parameter.

I tried runnning  awk  with your function on MacOS and got this error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1 in function attr source file 
 context is
        match(str,"@" attrname >>>  "=([^,/]*)", <<<
```

The "<<<" is indicating awk doesn't like that comma.  This is similar to your error message:

```
syntax error at or near ,
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely don't need the `match()` function's capture array to get the attribute value you're seeking :

```
echo 'april@token=sha256hmackey/0.ts' \
\
| mawk 'function attr(___,_,__,____) { ____="\32\21"

     if(_=="") { 
        _=$(_<_) }

     return \
         sub("[@]"(___)"=[^,\\/]*",____"&"____,_) \
             \
              ? substr(_=__[split(_,__,____)-\
                    (_~_)],index(_,"=")+(_~"")) : ""
   } { 
       print attr("token") }'

sha256hmackey
```